# Syntax for creating a Object implementing Parcelable from getParcelableExtra(intent_name)

Tags: android, android-intent, deserialization, parcelable, parcel

I am implementing the DataDroid model of RESTful communication and I have come across a compiler error while implementing my `SearchCriteria`. The problem is that in order to pass the `SearchCriteria` around as an intent extra, I had to make it implement `Parcelable`. However, my `Worker`'s `start` function requires a `SearchCriteria` class, leading to the error: `Required: my.classes.SearchCriteria; Found: android.os.Parcelable`.

Assuming that I've correctly implemented `Parcelable` for my `SearchCriteria` class, how can I quickly create an object from a parcel (where the parcel is found using `getParcelable Extra(INTENT_NAME)`?

Edit: <strike>I realize I can accomplish this quickly by making my constructor for `SearchCriteria` from `Parcel` public, but is there another way?</strike> Actually, this does not work - I confused a `Parcel` with a `Parcelable` thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you follow [the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and make SearchCriteria implements Parcelable properly, and your SearchCriteria has been properly constructed or instantiated from the underlying business layer, either from a Database or a Http server or etc.

To pass it to next activity by intent:

```
SearchCriteria searchCriteria = createSearchCriteria();
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("searchCriteria", searchCriteria);
startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve it from intent in next activity:

```
 SearchCriteria searchCriteria = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("searchCriteria");
 myWorker.search(searchCriteria);
```

In most situation, we don't need bother Parcel directly.